# How can I get http response headers in DocumentCompleted event on C# with GeckoFX 60?

Tags: c#, http, header, response, geckofx

I’d like to get HTTP response header in DocumentCompleted event (when page is loaded) for obtaining a response http code (200 or other) in GeckoFx 60.

Can anyone tell me how I can implement it on C#?

Thank you.